# Meaning of probability

Tags: probability

Suppose that at any day the probability that it will rain is $0.9$.
I am having little bit difficulty understanding the meaning of it.
Is there a chance that if we observed an incredibly large number of days, we still do not observe any rain? Or is it certain that it will rain sometimes?

Edit: Let's suppose we observed $X$ number of days. Then the probability that it didn't rain is $(0.1)^X$. If $X$ approaches infinity, isn't this basically $0$ though?

Comment: This statement implies that rain is never certain. It is a Bernoulli-experiment with success-probability $0.9$. If we wait $n$ days, then the probability that there is no rain on all those days, is $0.9^n$ , which is always positive. However, the probability that it rains within a finite number of days , is $1$.

Comment: Yes, There still is a chance (though very little) that it wont rain for large number of days. But in general, It would rain 9 out of 10 days.

Comment: let's suppose we observed X number of days. Then the probability that it didn't rain is (0.1)^X, if X approaches infinity, Isn't this basically 0 though

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  The experimental probability $0.9$ means that it has rained on $9/10$ of the past days with similar conditions.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Law of Large Numbers? I think it might be very relevant to your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

Comment: @phdstudent I said the same thing, didn't I?

Comment: What does "basically 0" mean to you?

Comment: @BasilBassam somehow I didn’t read your comment. I deleted mine as it does not add anything.

Comment: @m_t_. Equal to 0